# Android onTap start Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following code that starts an activity after detecting an onTap event.

Trouble is that more often than not it detects 2-3 taps from one user just pressing and so starts multiple.  Is there any way to dampen the effect and only open the once?

```
protected boolean onTap(int i) {

            Log.i("TAP","CALLED");


            myOverlayItem item =getItem(i);

            if (selectedName.equals(item.getTitle())){


                try{    
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(AppMain.this, DetailActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra( "int", i);
                myIntent.putExtra( "string", selectedName );
                AppMain.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", "Cannot launch", e);
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a boolean to true so you can make sure the code only runs once

```
boolean activityIsAlreadyRunning;


if(activityIsAlreadyRunning == false){
    if (selectedName.equals(item.getTitle())){
        try{    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AppMain.this, DetailActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra( "int", i);
            myIntent.putExtra( "string", selectedName );
            AppMain.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            activityIsAlreadyRunning = true;

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", "Cannot launch", e);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try reading the [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). This is how to launch your activity by single or multiple instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you issue an [`onClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)? This would launch just the once when clicked. Another possible solution might also be to simply set a public boolean variable within your parent class, and when your function is launched simply set `isRunning = true;` and right before it finishes it can set `isRunning = false;`. This would allow you to encase the launching of the event in a block as such:

```
if (!isRunning){
    onTap(integer);
}
```

This would make it so the method wasn't run on a touch, unless it wasn't currently already running. If this doesn't help, you could always compare your touch events `event.x` & `event.y` with the difference in `event.getEventTime()`. Then it could look something like this within your `onTouchEvent`:

```
if ((Math.abs(event.x - mLastEventX) > 2.0f) || 
        (Math.abs(event.y - mLastEventY) > 2.0f) || 
             ((event.getEventTime() - mLastEventTime) > 500f)){
    onTap(integer);
}
```

This would basically make it so it wouldn't launch unless any of the following were true:

- `((Math.abs(event.x - mLastEventX) > 2.0f)` or X value changes more than 2
- `(Math.abs(event.y - mLastEventY) > 2.0f)` or Y value changes more than 2
- `((event.getEventTime() - mLastEventTime) > 500f)` or the time has increased 500 millis

Without any more information as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish it's pretty hard for me to give you a solutions fit just for you. If none of these work though, try [`putExtras / getExtras`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) which deal with using an intent to put and get information throughout activity starts and finishes.